# Puppet agent on FreeBSD skipping runs

Tags: freebsd, puppet

I am experimenting with puppet and we are using FreeBSD on some servers. I noticed that the agent on the FreeBSD is for some reason skipping runs, i.e.:

```
May  6 09:19:15 eagle puppet-agent[66970]: Finished catalog run in 1.97 seconds
May  6 09:49:14 eagle puppet-agent[74306]: Finished catalog run in 1.72 seconds
May  6 10:19:29 eagle puppet-agent[80895]: Finished catalog run in 2.19 seconds
May  6 10:49:29 eagle puppet-agent[87436]: Finished catalog run in 2.37 seconds
May  6 12:19:26 eagle puppet-agent[7879]: Finished catalog run in 2.51 seconds
May  6 12:49:26 eagle puppet-agent[14528]: Finished catalog run in 2.64 seconds
```

As you can see, it skipped two runs (11:19 and 11:49). Unfortunately there are no more puppet lines in the log. I checked the puppet agent process and it was running all the time.

Puppet is version v3.1.1, built from ports, FreeBSD is 8.3-STABLE and I used the -dist config and I changed only a few options, most importantly

```
runinterval = 30m
```

The host is running under KVM virtualization so there are slight time movements:

```
May  6 10:20:28 eagle ntpd[656]: time reset -0.296053 s
May  6 11:19:03 eagle ntpd[656]: time reset -0.333463 s
May  6 12:21:38 eagle ntpd[656]: time reset -0.328728 s
```

As you can see there is 0.33sec move at cca the time when puppet should run but I am not sure if that is important or not. It is less than one second, its moving backwards and it was still a few seconds before the run should occur.

I know I can run puppet runs from cron but I would like to use daemon mode because I am planning to use the REST API.

Is there any way how to debug the "time trigger" mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to find the reason for this I "solved" the problem with the obvious workaround. I have a very long (1000 days) run interval in puppet.conf and I run the puppet cycles from cron via REST API.